# C++ как использовать методы класса до его объявления?

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, методы, build-error

Всем привет! Возможно ли использовать в С++ метод какого-то класса до его объявления?
Например как-то так (пример естественно не компилируется):

A.h:

```
struct B;
B* ptrB;

struct A
{
void doA();
}
```

B.h:

```
struct B
{
void doB();
}
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
    void A::doA()
    {
    ptrB->doB();
    }
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
//......dosomething
}
```

Или как-то извернуться, чтобы получилось так без перемещения В выше А? Ну или хотя бы передать как-то классу В, вызвав метод из А?

Comment: А если добавить в `A.cpp` `#include"B.h"`? Что именно мешает? Зависимость класса `A` от класса `B` у вас уже есть, так в чем проблема?

Comment: `B`  должно быть выше `A::doA()`

Comment: @Harry ну тогда будет повторное включение в main. А мне нужно, чтобы именно при такой2 последовательности объявлений работало. Ну предположим, что в B.h сделаю сверху #include "A.h", а в main будет только #include "B.h", то оно не скомпилируется, ибо B объявлен позже А и использовать его методы до его объявления нельзя.

Comment: @user7860670 а именно в той последовательности, что у меня, не получится никак?

Comment: Что значит "повторное включение"? Что именно вам не нравится? Если все компилируется и работает? *"а именно в той последовательности, что у меня, не получится никак"* — это как? Вы исправьте мой код, только ничего не трогайте? :)

Comment: @Harry ну проблема в том, что именно так, как я написал, оно НЕ компилируется. Ибо В объявляется после А и А ничего не знает о В. Я и хочу обойти эту штуку, чтобы из А, который объявлен раньше В можно было вызывать методы В. Может есть какой-то костыль или хитрость?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще раз и медленно...

**a.h**

```
struct B;
extern B* ptrB;

struct A
{
    void doA();
};
```

**b.h**

```
struct B
{
    void doB() {}
};
```

**a.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

void A::doA()
{
    ptrB->doB();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

B* ptrB;

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: а если у меня будет в B.h например подключена библиотека, то она будет подключена и в a.cpp и в main.cpp, а фактически в памяти не будут продублированы созданные ей объекты или определения?

Comment: Из *библиотеки* линковщик выбирает только то, на что есть ссылки в объектных файлах, и в одном экземпляре.

Comment: т.е. если я подключу библиотеку в кучу классов, то фактически она будет подключена в памяти только 1 раз?
И аналогичный вопрос про классы, если я h файл класса подключил в несколько cpp файлов других классов, то фактически класс из h файла будет скомпилирован только 1 раз?
А если я подключил библиотеку/класс в каком-то .срр файле, но не использовал оттуда ничего, то оно не будет повторно скомпилировано?

Comment: Класс из файла h может даже не быть скомпилирован ни разу, если вы им нигде не пользуетесь. О библиотеках — вы же не задаете такой вопрос, когда пишете, скажем, `cout <<` в разных cpp-файлах?